# ActivityIndicator running after press the BackButton

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I have a page with a list of items and when some is selected, the ActivityIndicator turns on and goes to another page, turning off. When i am in this new page and i click the BackButton on NavigationPage, i return to the page with the List of items, but the problem is that the ActivityIndicator is on (persists). How can i fix it ?

[List Page]

```
public partial class ResultadosBuscados : ContentPage
    {
        public ResultadosBuscados(IEnumerable dadosPesquisados)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
            ListaBuscados.ItemsSource = dadosPesquisados;

        }

        public void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            stackActivity.IsVisible = true;
            Envolvido envolvSelec = (Envolvido)e.SelectedItem;
                if (envolvSelec == null)
                    return;

            IsBusy = false;
            stackActivity.IsVisible = false;
            this.Navigation.PushAsync(new EnvolvidoDetalhe(envolvSelec));

            this.ListaBuscados.SelectedItem = null;
        }

    }
```

[part of XAML code]

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stackActivity" IsVisible="False" Padding="12"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">
    <Frame Padding="50" OutlineColor="Black" HasShadow="true" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" Opacity="0.8" BackgroundColor="Black" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
          <ActivityIndicator  IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color ="#F4B400"/>
          <Label Text="Aguarde..." TextColor="#F4B400"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </Frame>
  </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you set `IsBusy = true;` somewhere in your `EnvolvidoDetalhe` page or in it's ViewModel and you never set it back to `false` before the user hits the back button? I would suggest either setting `IsBusy = false;` in`EnvolvidoDetalhe.OnDisappearing()` or do it at the top of `ResultadosBuscados.OnAppearing()`. Does that fix it? If so, figure out where you are setting `IsBusy` to `true` and not setting it back to `false`

Comment: @hvaughan3 The defult is false! On the others pages that don´t use a ListView and OnItemSelected, it Works nice ! I can go forward and back normally. The problem just happens when is in a OnItemSelected ! I tried to debug after click the BackButton, but the page ResultadosBuscados suppose to have the isbusy = false as a default.

Comment: I am not sure if `IsBusy` gets reset when you change pages or if `IsBusy` stays the same value no matter what page you go to. Did you try setting `IsBusy` to `false` in `ResultadosBuscados.OnAppearing()`? Actually reading `IsBusy`'s comment remarks, it says "Setting IsBusy to true on multiple pages at once will cause the global activity indicator to run until both are set back to false. It is the authors job to unset the IsBusy flag before cleaning up a Page."

Comment: My `ActivityIndicator`s always also bind `IsVisible` like this: `<ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color ="#F4B400"/>`

Comment: @hvaughan3 i did this ! IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"  but not worked. Also, who is .OnAppearing() ?

Comment: See my answer edit below for the `OnAppearing()` override example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, check for anywhere that `IsBusy` is being set to `true` and not being set back to `false`. The bindings do not go away when the page changes and is brought back up.

Also, I found this awesome code that has worked well for me most of the time and which makes it so that you do not need to worry about setting `IsBusy` to `false` (though be warned that they are doing some fancy stuff so that it can be set in the ViewModel, you could instead add the code to a base `ContentPage` that all your pages derive from if you do not want to get it working in your ViewModel).

Code to make it work:
https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/4abddfab1e1cb0e7d14925aa27cae7685dbd5f38/Sport.Mobile.Shared/ViewModels/BaseViewModel.cs#L138

Example of it being used:
https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/04f6b99cec752a106d51566ed96231beacfd2568/Sport.Mobile.Shared/ViewModels/AvailableLeaguesViewModel.cs#L41

*Edit:

OnAppearing override example:

```
public partial class ResultadosBuscados : ContentPage {

    public ResultadosBuscados(IEnumerable dadosPesquisados) {
        IsBusy = false;
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        ListaBuscados.ItemsSource = dadosPesquisados;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing() {
        base.OnAppearing();
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Niiiiiiiice !! Worked... 
Thanks a lot for the attention !

Comment: @MCFer No problem, happy to help. But like I said, if that worked, it means that somewhere you are setting `IsBusy` to `true` and you are not setting it back to `false` so you should search your solution for all the places that you use `IsBusy` to figure out where that might be happening.

Comment: I did this ! Don´t have... Maybe its a bug when has a ViewCell and using ItemSelected ! Because on the others pages, it doesn´t happen. I looked for every IsBusy.