# Network Activity Spinner Spins Forever

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm building a Xamarin Forms app and have a problem with the network activity spinner in the Status Bar (iOS) continuing to spin forever.  Below is the code I'm using to display a loading screen.

```
private async Task ExecuteConfigureCampaignCommand()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
        {
            return;
        }

        IsBusy = true;
        //ConfigureCampaignCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        bool showAlert = false;
        string campaign = null;

        try
        {
            campaign = CrossSecureStorage.Current.GetValue(SettingNames.Campaign);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(campaign))
            {
                StatusMessage = "Blah";
                OnPropertyChanged("StatusMessage");

                await Task.Delay(1000);

                StatusMessage = "Blah";
                OnPropertyChanged("StatusMessage");

                await Task.Delay(700);

                StatusMessage = "Blah";
                OnPropertyChanged("StatusMessage");

                await Task.Delay(500);

                MessagingService.Current.SendMessage<string>(SettingNames.NavigationSales, campaign);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var abc = e;
            showAlert = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            //ConfigureCampaignCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        }

        if (showAlert)
        {
            await page.DisplayAlert("Uh Oh :(", "Unable to load campaign.", "OK");
        }
    }
```

This is called from a command:

```
public Command ConfigureCampaignCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return configureCampaignCommand ?? (configureCampaignCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteConfigureCampaignCommand(), () => { return !IsBusy; }));
        }
    }
```

Which is called from OnAppearing:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        viewModel.ConfigureCampaignCommand.Execute(null);
    }
```

The logic is fine - the View that I expect is loaded, however the network activity spinner continues spinning.  If I add a 1 second delay:

```
                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1), () =>
                {
                    MessagingService.Current.SendMessage<string>(SettingNames.NavigationSales, campaign);

                    return false;
                });
```

The spinner stops once the new view is loaded.  If I remove the await Task.Delay's, the spinner stops once the view is loaded, however the loading messages are not visible to the user.

My question is, why does the network spinner continue?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change IsBusy

```
 OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
```

As you are calling this for your other properties but not for IsBusy I guess that this is probably the reason the change doesn't get picked up.

Comment: I'm using an MVVM Helper library, that defines IsBusy and calls OnPropertyChange("IsBusy")

Comment: Does ExecuteConfigureCampaignCommand get dispatched on the UI thread?

Comment: I assume we are talking about this property https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Page.IsBusy/

Comment: It is executing on the UI thread - at first I thought the await Task.Delay was pushing it to a background thread, by that's not happening

Comment: No await will always return to the previous dispatcher/thread unless you tell it not to. You would have to start the task on the task pool or something. But that is not the problem it seems.

Comment: Could be that you are setting IsBusy somewhere else. Maybe this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850631/activityindicator-running-after-press-the-backbutton

Comment: I'll check where I'm setting IsBusy, but I'm fairly sure lol true's are getting set to false